# Cannot read property „id” of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

The thing is I am trying to make a command which show how much coins a user has, but every time I type the command it just returns „cannot read property „id” of undefined”.

Here is the code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
let coins = require("../coins.json");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  //!coins
    let pUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
    if(!coins[pUser.id]){
    coins[pUser.id] = {
      coins: 0
    };
  }

    if(!coins[message.author.id]){
    coins[message.author.id] = {
      coins: 0
    };
  }

  let pCoins = coins[pUser.id].coins;
  let uCoins = coins[message.author.id].coins;


  if (!pUser) { 
      message.channel.send(`**${message.author}**: Ai manglit **${uCoins}** puncte de neață!`);
  } else {
      message.channel.send(`**${pUser}**: Ai manglit **${pCoins}** puncte de neață!`);
    }
}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "neti"
}
```

Also here is my coins.json file:

```
{
   "108225935509057536":{
      "coins":3,
      "id":"108225935509057536"
   },
   "513103473571790857":{
      "coins":579
   },
   "274234269944119296":{
      "coins":436
   },
   "289874882974711808":{
      "coins":48
   },
   "282255872871235584":{
      "coins":372
   },
   "260746723805233153":{
      "coins":721
   },
   "595994062864121872":{
      "coins":18
   },
   "225239396339679232":{
      "coins":362
   },
   "346946888634728450":{
      "coins":59
   },
   "186871446125936644":{
      "coins":159
   },
   "279263622247743488":{
      "coins":669
   },
   "126321478550552576":{
      "coins":1
   },
   "469899490686664714":{
      "coins":1
   },
   "242381361158029314":{
      "coins":13
   },
   "224095971955441665":{
      "coins":11
   },
   "547093167040757770":{
      "coins":26
   },
   "252882616297062400":{
      "coins":4
   },
   "261602781981310976":{
      "coins":59
   },
   "254002772679196682":{
      "coins":6
   },
   "371414290156093440":{
      "coins":20
   },
   "188347467874435073":{
      "coins":9
   },
   "449120976870047744":{
      "coins":122
   },
   "286178947148939265":{
      "coins":10
   },
   "539794625972404225":{
      "coins":0
   },
   "491701834193305600":{
      "coins":2
   },
   "280730839946493953":{
      "coins":13
   }
}
```

Comment: can you post your `../coins.json`??

Comment: log your `message` using console.log(message). looks like it doesn't have author in it.

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: @ImEzreallyBad First at all, on which line you have this error ?

pUser.id i imagine ?

Comment: @ShigehiroKamisama it comes from line 7.

Comment: @ImEzreallyBad Yes then it's your pUser that is undefined, try my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This block will always undefined, pUser its a guild.member and dont have property `id`

```js
if(!coins[pUser.id]){
  coins[pUser.id] = {
    coins: 0
  };
}
```

The fist part of this code will return collection of `message.author` so you will see [object,object]

```js
if (!pUser) { 
  message.channel.send(`**${message.author}**: Ai manglit **${uCoins}** puncte de neață!`);
} else {
  message.channel.send(`**${pUser}**: Ai manglit **${pCoins}** puncte de neață!`);
}
```

The right way is:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
let coins = require("../coins.json");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  let targetMember = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.get(args[0])
  if(!targetMember) targetMember = message.member

  if(!coins[targetMember.user.id]){
    coins[targetMember.user.id] = {
      coins: 0
    };
  }

  let pCoins = coins[targetMember.user.id].coins;

  message.channel.send(`**${targetMember.user.id}**: Ai manglit **${pCoins}** puncte de neață!`);
}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "neti"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually in your code you get the user that is mentionned or the user you get if you type an id in first arg

/coin @john#0000 or /coin 192367487362 (this is an example)

You have to add a condition to protect your code from error like that :

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  //!coins
    let pUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);

    if(!pUser) {
      // Do something if no user was mentionned and no id was sent with the first argument
      return;
    }

    if(!coins[pUser.id]){
    coins[pUser.id] = {
      coins: 0
    };
  }

    if(!coins[message.author.id]){
    coins[message.author.id] = {
      coins: 0
    };
  }

  let pCoins = coins[pUser.id].coins;
  let uCoins = coins[message.author.id].coins;


  if (!pUser) { 
      message.channel.send(`**${message.author}**: Ai manglit **${uCoins}** puncte de neață!`);
  } else {
      message.channel.send(`**${pUser}**: Ai manglit **${pCoins}** puncte de neață!`);
    }
}
```

Comment: after I replace it just says `TypeError: message.guild.members is not a function`

Comment: @ImEzreallyBad Mh, when you call your command, you mention a member ?

Comment: The error shows up only when I do not do that. But if I tag myself it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @ImEzreallyBad Oh then it's normal, wait 2 seconds i will update my answer

Comment: @ImEzreallyBad You have to mention a member or use it's id, without that the pUser will be undefined and your code will not work (without a return in case the user is undefined)

Comment: lol, it shows the same error but it now it works as it should be. When I dont tag someone it show how much coins I have and when I tag someone it shows how much coins that user has. Interesting how the command works but the error never got away.

Answer (score 0):

const data = {"108225935509057536": { coins: 3, id: "108225935509057536" }};

console.log(data["108225935509057536"]);

try this

Comment: This isn't a solution to the user's problem.